# zend framework 2 Routing with UTF-8 Regex Pattern

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework2

I want my routing support persian character but when use x{600}-\x{6FF} in regex path,app give me a 404 Error (Page not found)

My zf2 routing config :

```
  'result' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(                    
                    'route'    => '/Result[/:name]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'name' => '[\sa-zA-Z0-9_.-x{600}-\x{6FF}]*',

                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Result',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

and I add `u` to end of regex in Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment.php

```
if ($pathOffset !== null) {
            $result = preg_match('(\G' . $regex . ')u', $path, $matches,null, $pathOffset);
        } else {
            $result = preg_match('(^' . $regex . '$)u', $path, $matches);
        }
```

My URL like this :

```
http://localhost/test/Result/A.8.کلمه
```

Comment: Try `'[\sa-zA-Z0-9_.\x{600}-\x{6FF}-]*'`.

Comment: I try with above code but give me 404 Error

Comment: It seems you need to pass `rawurldecode($path);` to `preg_match`. Please try with the above regex.

Comment: I pass  rawurldecode($path) to preg_match in Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment.php like this : $result = preg_match('(\G' . $regex . ')u', rawurldecode($path), $matches,null, $pathOffset); But give me 404 Error again

Comment: Why do you need to pass the offset, BTW? I'd just use `preg_match('(\G' . $regex . ')u', rawurldecode($path), $matches);`. Offset is counted in bytes. Are you sure it is calculated correctly?

Comment: Segment.php is a native Zf2 class And  When remove $pathOffset param, app give me 404 Error with all request Even with English char

Comment: Segment.php is a native Zf2 class And When remove $pathOffset param, app give me 404 Error with all request Even with English char

Comment: Just to rule out the escape issues, try also with `"[\\sa-zA-Z0-9_.\\x{600}-\\x{6FF}-]*"`

Comment: I try with [\\sa-zA-Z0-9_.\\x{600}-\\x{6FF}-]* But give  404 error

Comment: I got it . use % in regex pattern  Like this : [%\sa-zA-Z0-9_.-]*

Comment: But it does not match any of the Persian letters, does it?

Comment: I now test it with any Persian char and it work fine,Thanks a lot  for response

Comment: I added an answer. If it helped, please consider accepting and upvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misplaced hyphen inside a character class issue and a missing `\` before the first `x{600}`. Here is how the [hyphen changes the meaning of the pattern](https://regex101.com/r/lZ8yS1/1):

[image]

To fix it, you need to move it to the end of the character class:

```
'[\sa-zA-Z0-9_.\x{600}-\x{6FF}-]*'
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZ8yS1/2).

Note that if you need to add any more characters to the pattern, you should be careful with `[`, `]`, `-`, `/`. They must be escaped to avoid issues. E.g., adding a `%`:

```
'[%\sa-zA-Z0-9_.\x{600}-\x{6FF}-]*'
```

Next issue is that you need to pass `rawurldecode($path)` to the `preg_match` instead of just `$path`.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please consider also upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).